# Word cut off in TTTAttributedLabel

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I am using TTTAttributedLabel but now when i try to show some link then it cut the word from the center like you can see in attached image the word "fun" is cut off after word "f" and "un" appears on next line. but i want that the full word should show on first line or in next line. Any help.

[image]

[image]

```
if ([_label isKindOfClass:[TTTAttributedLabel class]])
            {
                TTTAttributedLabel *tttLabel=(TTTAttributedLabel *)_label;

                                        [tttLabel setDelegate:self];

                    [tttLabel setDataDetectorTypes:UIDataDetectorTypeLink|UIDataDetectorTypePhoneNumber];
                    [tttLabel setLineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];



                [tttLabel setText:attributedText];
                if ([dic objectForKey:@"texttolink"]!=nil)
                {
                    [tttLabel addLinkToURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[dic objectForKey:@"hyperlink"]] withRange:[text rangeOfString:[dic objectForKey:@"texttolink"] options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch]];
                }



            }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the latest version of TTTAttributedLabel, the default `linkAttributes` property was updated to have word wrap by default. Make sure that both the label and the `linkAttributes` have the desired line break mode (`lineBreakMode` property for the label; `NSMutableParagraphStyle lineBreakMode` for `linkAttributes`).

Answer (score 1):

Try setting `lineBreakMode` to `NSLineBreakByWordWrapping`:

```
label.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
```

Comment: posted some code. it's seems to me a bug in TTTAttributedLabel

Comment: If you remove the links it works? Can you post also the code where you create the label?